# Magento 2: save product description for adminhtml programmatically

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, product-attribute, store-view, repository

I cannot see description and short description attributes of the product in adminhtml after saving:

```
/** @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface */
protected $_manStore;
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface */
protected $_repoProd;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $desc
 * @param string $shortDesc
 * @param int $status
 * @param float $price
 * @param float $weight
 */
protected function _updateProduct($product, $name, $desc, $shortDesc, $status, $price, $weight)
{
    $product->setName($name);
    $product->setDescription($desc);
    $product->setShortDescription($shortDesc);
    $product->setStatus($status);
    $product->setPrice($price);
    $product->setWeight($weight);
    $this->_manStore->setCurrentStore("0");
    $this->_repoProd->save($product);
}
```

Description & short desc. attributes are saved for default store view instead (store_id=1):

[image]

How can I save these attributes visible for adminhtml using Magento way (not SQL direct updates)?

Comment: I must ask why you use underscores in front of your variable and function names. It's an old agreement between programmers that it means the variable or function is private. As of modern PHP versions, you can declare visibility as you are already doing. It is even officially deprecated: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

Comment: I'm old, my code is old, my old code uses old agreements.

Comment: Whenever I edit an old module with such names I refactor it. Easily done with a proper EDI like PhpStorm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the current store by name:

```
$this->_manStore->setCurrentStore("admin");
```

Comment: yes, store code instead of store ID works, both for `admin` and `default` stores.

Comment: Old, but life saving ! Thanks for the tip.